# shapefile damaged after editing in ArcMap 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, shapefile, autocad

I drew a layer on Autocad and exported it to a shapefile.
I edited this layer on Arcmap. After editing the layer it is corrupted.
I use Shapechk to fix it however I will need to edit plenty of layers and shapechk wouldn't be practical for me.i need an automated method

Comment: So it works properly but you are looking for a batch solution, maybe something somewhat automated?

Comment: So, is there a question here?  I can't tell what you want.  Is your corrupted shapefile after editing repeatable?  Does it corrupt every shapefile or just the one? Etc., etc.

Comment: Are you sure the shapefile wasn't created in a non-conformant form, even before modifying it in Desktop?

Comment: To which "tool" do you refer: AutoCAD, ArcMap, or Shapechk?

Comment: Shape files go bad quickly, especially if edited over network, because there is many files to update they are prone to locking with virus checker, another application looking at it etc.. Import into file geodatabase and edit there - much more stable.

Comment: I imported it to a file geodatabase and now i can edit it with no problem as many time as i want. It worked, thanks Michel Miles-Stimson.

Answer (score 1):

Before using shapechck, you can use the "[repair geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003v000000)" tool in Arcmap. Right-click on it to launch it in batch mode.